# CKFinder: Create An Upload Log

Tags: javascript, php, upload, ckfinder

Is there any way to create a log for each upload done in CKFinder 2.4.2? e.g. every upload actions logs the uploader, the uploaded file, and the time of upload at a .txt file, so I can know who uploads what at what time.
I don't really know what to do, except by looking at `\ckfinder\core\connector\php\php5\CommandHandler\Fileupload.php`  but still I dont know what to do there.
I also looked at
[this link](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Server_Side_Integration/The_Commands/FileUpload) but still I got no idea. Where can I access such javascript like listed at the link, and if there is something i can do about that regarding to adding actions on a completed upload action:
`<script type="text/javascript">
   window.parent.OnUploadCompleted( 0, '' ) ;
</script>`

Comment: Did you look at the [UserActionsLogger](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/howto.html#howto_logging_actions) sample plugin?

Comment: @AnnaTomanek I forgot to mention that I used CKFinder 2.4.2, but now I have migrated to CKFinder 3.0.0 to be able to use that plugin. The migration was successful initially, But after I put the plugin at the plugins folder and change the config.php as the documentation says:
`$config['pluginsDirectory'] = __DIR__ . '/plugins';
$config['plugins'] = array('UserActionsLogger');`, I can't upload anything (the cache folder still got the cache file, though). And I didn't see the log file as intended. Maybe I'm missing something?